# How to position this spinner in a td

Tags: html, css

I would like to do this (see picture)-

[image]

I have this for the moment-

[image]

My html code is-

```
<td data-sort-initial="true" data-value="azerty" style="padding:5px;">
    <input class="form-control input-sm edit2" data-nom_champ="contact_label" data-id_ecole_contact="9" name="contact_label" type="text" value="azerty">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="waiting_9" style="display:none;position:relative;left:0px;top:2px;"></i>
</td>
```

I can modify the top and left values, but is it the right method ? Is it because I ma in a td element that it does not work ? Should I place a div instead ?

Thanks for your help

Dominique

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the td style to be

> position: relative;

and change to **i** style to:

> position: absolute; right: 6px; top: 4px;

final code will look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative">
          <input type="text"/>
          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="waiting_9" style="display:none;position: absolute; right: 6px; top: 4px;"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/d1xasmLd/9/

Comment: The code you provided is incorrect.  The spinner shows outside the input, whereas the OP wants it INSIDE the input.

Comment: Upvoted as the correction is the right answer. This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using

```
position: absolute;
```

for your element

find the working [fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/ayam74Lx/1/)

Comment: The code you provided is incorrect. The spinner shows outside the input, whereas the OP wants it INSIDE the input.

Comment: The JSFiddle you provided shows the spinner to the right of the input field (outside of it).  Did you upload the correct JSFiddle?